# Drupal Help - Warning: Unresponsive Script - Everytime Goes into or out of Block Edit Mode

Tags: javascript, drupal, scripting, drupal-6

Every time goes in and out admin-build-block page, the annoying "Warning: Unresponsive Script" pop-up shows up along with such details:

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.

How can we get rid of this annoying thing?  This is the only page experiencing this problem, other nodes at the website have no such problem at all.

Many thanks for your kind help or guidance.  Happy Winter

Answer (score 1):

First, disable Javascript optimization on admin/settings/performance before you start debugging.

If the problem disappears, it's caused by the JS optimization and you should file a bug in the Drupal issue queue on drupal.org (search first to avoid duplicates).

If the problem persists, the error message will show in which file the error is caused. If it's your own script, fix it or ask for help to fix it. If it's caused by a script that came with an existing module, try to fix it and post a patch in the issue queue of that module. If you can't fix it, file a bug report in the issue queue.

If the steps above are not possible or too difficult, try to provide more information: post the script, error messages, browser name and version, drupal version, theme name, installed modules, anything you think is relevant. Also try switching back to the Garland theme to check if the problem is caused by your theme.

Comment: marcvangend, 
Many thanks for your great answer. Happy Winter

Comment: Coder, you're welcome, thanks for the feedback. Don't forget to vote-up and/or accept the answer if you feel that's appropriate.